# Change Facebook header text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

How do you change the Facebook tag in the top left of the page to some other string by pasting javascript into the address bar of the browser?

Comment: And why do you want to do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to do that? Surely Stack Overflow is a thought provoking discussion forum.

Comment: <Insert information on how to use Alt+F4 key combination to enable malicious javascript in address bar mode here>

Comment: @jacktheripper: **Absolutely *not***. Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A; it is _explicitly_ **not** a "thought-provoking discussion forum", and we have question-closing FAQ entries to cover such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 javascript:document.getElementById('pageLogo').childNodes[0].setAttribute('style','background:url(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png) no-repeat;background-size: 100px;');
```

Just replace the image with something else.